# The Space RP^n # RP^n (connected sum of two copies of RP^n) diffeomorphic to Quotient space of S^1X S^{n-1}

Tags: algebraic-topology

How the space $$(S^1×S^{n−1})/\mathbb{Z}_2,$$ where $(z_1,z_2)\sim(\bar{z_1}, -z_2),$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^n \text{#}\mathbb{R}P^n$?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933), and [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: It would be better if you can add some context to this question.

Answer (score 1):

**Deliberately not a complete answer, but a guide to getting there.**

(1) You should really check out [this guide](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) so that you can ask questions in a more-readable way.
$$
\newcommand{\rp}{\mathbb RP^n}
$$
(2) Let me try to help with showing that these two things are *homeomorphic* at least. Let's look at $S^1$ as the unit circle in the plane. Then the conjugation map is just $(x, y) \mapsto (x, -y)$. And let's call the quotient (which we suspect is homeomorphic to $\rp \# \rp$) by the name $Q$, and call the quotient map
$$
p: S^1 \times S^{n-1} \to Q.
$$
While I'm naming things, let's call the domain of $p$, i.e., $S^1 \times S^{n-1}$, by the name $U$, to save some typing.

I'm going to divide $U$ into three parts (like Gaul). Each will have the form $B \times S^{n-1}$, where $B$ is a subset of $S^1$.

1. For the "middle", $U_0$, the set $B$ will be all points $(x, y)$ of $S^1$ where $|x| \le 0.5$. So $B$ consists of an arc near the top of the circle and another arc containing the bottom point of the circle.
2. For the "left", $U_1$, the set $B$ will be all points $(x, y)$ where $x < -0.5$, i.e., it's an arc containing the left-most point of the circle.
3. For the "right", $U_2$, the set $B$ will be points with $x > 0.5$.

I'll now try to show that $p(U_0)$ is homeomorphic to $I \times S^{n-1}$, which you can think of as the "tube" part of the connect-sum, while $P(U_1)$ looks like $\mathbb \rp$ with a disk removed, and similarly for $P(U_2)$.

At that point, we'll have that $P(U)$ consists of 3 parts -- a punctured $\rp$, another punctured $\rp$, and a tube between them.

I'll leave to you the job of showing that the map $p$ is continuous, and (because this depends on your exact description of the smooth structure on the connect-sum) that it's smooth, and then presumably you'll be done.

So the first step is to look at the $U_0^{+} \times S^{n-1}$ That's exactly the same as the image of $U_0^{+} \times S^{n-1}$ under $p$, where $U_0^{+}$ consists of points of $U_0$ with positive $y$-coordinate, i.e., the upper arc of the circle where $-0.5 \le x \le 0.5$. Why is it the same? Well, if $((x, y), X)$ is a point of $U_0^{-} \times S^{n-1}$, then
$$
p( (x, y), X) = p( (x, -y), -X )
$$
i.e., the image of this "lower point", paired with $X \in S^{n-1}$, is the same as the image of an "upper point", paired with $-X$. So to understand
$p(U_0 \times S^{n-1})$, it's sufficient to examine $p(U_0^{+} \times S^{n-1})$. But when we restrict $p$ to *that* set, it's 1-to-1 and bicontinuous, so the image is homeomorphic to $U_0^{+} \times S^{n-1}$, i.e., the image is homeomorphic to $I \times S^{n-1}$. So that's going to be the "tube" in the connect-sum.

Now what about $U_2 \times S^{n-1}$? [The exact same argument will apply to $U_1 \times S^{n-1}$, so I won't write it out.] What I need to show is that
$p(U_2 \times S^{n-1})$ looks like a punctured $\rp$. Now $\rp$ is the quotient of $S^n$ by the antipodal map. Let's "puncture" it by removing a small disk around the image of the north pole. In the domain $S^n$, this means removing a small disk around each of the north and south pole, so we're left with a quotient of $K = I \times S^{n-1}$, where the $I$ represents the north-south coordinate, and the $S^{n-1}$ is the equatorial sphere, with the quotient taking the form $(z, X) \equiv (-z, -X)$.

Added note: the quotient map is a 2-to-1 map from $K$ to the image

I think I'll leave it to you to see that the quotient of $K$ by that equivalence is the same as the quotient of $U_0 \times S^{n-1}$ by the original equivalence.

Added note: You comment asks why $p(U_1 \times S^{n-1}$ looks like $I \times \rp$. I'm going to show you a subset of $K$ that maps $1-to-1$ to $I \times \rp$ under that quotient. Let's start with just $\{(0, 1)\} \times S^{n-1}$. That maps, 2-to-1, to $M \times \rp$, where $M$ is a single point. To make the map 1-to-1, let's look at just "half" of $S^{n-1}$. Points of $S^{n-1}$ look like $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$, where $\sum x_i^2 = 1$, right? Well, let's consider only those with $x_1 \ge 0$, and call that $G_1$. Clearly that set covers $\rp$ just fine, and most points of $\rp$ (those where the $x_1$ coordinate is nonzero) correspond to a single point in $G_1$. But when $x_1 = 0$, we have $(0, 1, 0, \ldots, 0)$ and $(0, -1, 0, \ldots, 0)$ both mapping to the same point in $\rp$. We fix this by saying that $G_2$ is the subset of $G_1$ consisting of points where $x_2 \ge 0$. Proceeding like this, we get to $G_n$, a subset of $S^{n-1}$ that maps 1-to-1 onto $\rp$. Now consider $U_0^{+} \times G_n$, where $U_0^{+}$ is all points of $U_0$ with $y \ge 0$. This set -- $U_0^{+} \times G_n$ -- maps to $I \times \rp$ quite nicely. I think it's a good exercise to see, with paper and scissors, why this works in the case where $n = 2$. When you see that clearly, the higher dimensions will follow.

Comment: Thanks, for giving me an idea of the proof. But I still doubt how would see P(U_2 x  S^{n-1}) looks like punctured RP^n?  You mean [a,b]x S^{n-1}/ z_2 is nothing but punctured RP^n? BUT HOW?

Comment: By the  way...the first paragraph of this question -- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4768131/why-are-quotients-by-free-group-actions-well-behaved -- explains why the quotient is a smooth manifold (whose structure is compatible with the quotient map).

Comment: See added note.

Comment: It’s sad that this probably great answer is at risk of being deleted due to the OP being “low quality”. If that happens maybe you can repost this and then answer your own question

Comment: Yeah. MSE is very different from what it was a few years back when I was more active. A combination of aggressive closing of questions and (my guess) ChatGPT giving quicker answers has made it a bit of a ghost town, sadly. Sure OP looks "low quality," but OP also self-describes as a PhD student in topology, so they need some help in seeing basic stuff...and I can provide that, unless all my answers get deleted. :( I feel like "I'm a PhD student in topology" **is** context, and having once been that person... well... it's sad that others don't.